# Want to notify on when an item is inserted into arraylist using callback in java

Tags: java, callback

I am very much interested in callback methods implementation in java. I went through
      some examples on internet but I still not much more confident to solve this problem.
      my problem is my program must notify with a message when an item is inserted into
      a list with callback methods implementation. How can I solve this Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should consider creating a *List Decorator* (Design Pattern) that would allow you to be notified of every `List` implementation by only changing one line in you existing code.

This is the general idea:

```
public interface ListListener<E> {
    void onAdd(List list, E element);
    void onDelete(List list, E element);
    ...
}

public class EventfulList<E> implements List {
    private List<E> decoratedList;
    private ListListener<E> listener;

    public EventfulList(final List targetList) {
        decoratedList = targetList;
    }

    public void setListener(final ListListener<E> listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public boolean add(E element) {
        final boolean result = decoratedList.add(element);
        doOnAdd(element);
        return result;
    }

    public void doOnAdd(final E element) {
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onAdd(this, element);
        }
    }
}
```

You would use it something like this:

```
public class ListEventsDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Assume this is existing code.
        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> list2 = new LinkedList<String>();

        // This is new code.
        ListListener<String> listener = new ListListener<String>() {
            public void onAdd(List list, E element) {
                System.out.println(String.format("'%s' added to %s.",
                    element.toString(), list.getClass().getName()));
            }

            public void onDelete(List list, E element) {
                System.out.println(String.format("'%s' removed from %s.",
                    element.toString(), list.getClass().getName()));
            }
        }

        list1 = new EventfulList<String>(list1);
        list2 = new EventfulList<String>(list2);
        ((EventfulList) list1).setListener(listener);
        ((EventfulList) list2).setListener(listener);

        // Existing code again.
        list1.add("123");
        list2.add("abc");
    }
}
```

It might look like an overkill at first but it would require less changes to existing code, and you don't need to subclass every `List` implementation to monitor it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this implementation

Answer (score 2):

Extend the list class you use (or implement the List interface yourself). Define callback interface e.g. AddListCallback with just one method

```
void itemAdded(Object item)
```

In the constructor of your list pass the callback interface implementation and store it in a field. Override the

```
void add(int index, E element);
```

method of List interface (and may be some more methods if necessary). call `super.add(index, element)` and then `storedCallback.itemAdded(element)` to call the callback's method.

UPDATE: You can use AOP based approach See e.g. http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-aop-examples-advice/ and listen the add() method call but it seems to be more difficult approach.

Comment: Is it not possible without implementing  list interface ?

Comment: See UPDATE of the answer

Answer (score 1):

Do something like

```
public class MyList extends ArrayList{
public boolean add(Object o){
    boolean b = super.add(o);
    callBack();
    return b;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    List myList = new MyList();
    myList.add("abc");
    System.out.println(myList);
}

public void callBack(){
    //Operation to do in callback
    System.out.println("in callback");
}
```

}

you need to extends List implementer class that you want to use and then override add method.